# Moving only old files to another dir

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have /files dir with lots of files. I want to move them to /archive dir. Moving process takes few minutes since there are huge numer of files.

During moving process I created a new file named *new-file.jpg* in /files dir. 
Will *new-file.jpg* be moved to /archive dir or will not?

I need to have only all old files (files existed when I started zip process) in /archived dir. How to achieve that?

Comment: save timestamp when starting the moving process into a variable as start point and check if moved file `mtime` is less than stored value

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a glob pattern as in `tar cf old.tar.gz /files/*.dat` then this glob pattern will be resolved by bash before the command is actually called. So the tar command would be called as `tar cf old.tar.gz /files/1.dat /files/2.dat ...`, which means files created while tar is executing will not be included.

This can be visualized:

```
files=(/files/*.dat)
touch /files/new.dat
printf '%s\n' ${files[@]} | grep -P '^/files/new.dat$'
```